# Internationalized Django app back to English

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization, django-cms

My django app is in an European language. Now I want to revert back to English and do internationalization and localization properly. I did this in setting.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
]
```

But the whole application is still not showing in English. Am I missing something here? 
PS. The app is also using Django-CMS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do multiple things:

- Write all strings in one language, in your case English.

You then need to mark all strings for translation:

- Add `trans` tags arounds all strings in templates (from the `i18n` template tag library), see [internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/internationalization/) in the documentation. This is related to gettext: a common library for handling translation. By adding `trans` tags around strings they will be included in a huge list of strings that need to be translated (see `.po` and `.mo` below).
- Add `_()` around all strings in the Python source code (from `django.utils.translation`, also see internationalization in the docs). This is also related to gettext and this includes those strings as well in the gettext language files.

You then need to create the language files and add the translations to those files:

- Create the gettext `.po` and `.mo` files which contain the translation strings. In these files you can write the translated strings. These two files are often placed in the `/locale/` directory. For each language you need to write the translated strings and put them in these files. More details on these language files can be found in the Django documentation on [localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/).

It's good to read Django's overview on [internationalization and localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/) (often called i18n) as the above explanation is only the general way to do it. The exact technical details are in the documentation.

Note that the above is only for translating static strings that are part of your Python code or templates. If you want to translate URLs or Django models then you'll need to install additional libraries or use other existing Django functionality. For example, in Django 1.4 some functionality was added to translate URLs but for earlier Django versions you'll need to use a library / Django app for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simeon. Well, yeah I know these steps and I created a demo app before jumping into this app. My question is that the application is written using django internationalization/localization steps and when I try to revert back to English, it am failing.

Is it problem with strings? The string used in this app is mixed, English and Non-English.

Comment: You can't have mixed strings: all strings need to be in one lanuage and you can then change the language using the translation files. Django then knows to load the correct language files when you change the current language of a request.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again. I guess this is reason my app is not rendered in English. Will fix it :)

Comment: My app is also using Django-CMS. I guess it is related to CMS. Any idea?

Comment: Django-CMS is also translatable but it requires additional configuration (such as the different languages), see http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/configuration.html#i18n-and-l10n and http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/i18n.html

Answer (score 0):

Simeon's answer covers all ground but here, I have found something that might help anyone test the localization in development environment.

If you are native European then your browser may request the `accepted-language` as `es`, just for the example.

Now, you want to test the English language translation in your local environment then you need to consider below possibilities.

As per [django-book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter19.html)'s refrence:

You will need to put [LocaleMiddleware](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter19.html#how-django-discovers-language-preference)

> 1> First, it looks for a django_language key in the current user’s
>   session.
>
> 2> Failing that, it looks for a cookie.
>
> 3> Failing that, it looks at the Accept-Language HTTP header. This
>   header is sent by your browser and tells the server which language(s)
>   you prefer, in order by priority. Django tries each language in the
>   header until it finds one with available translations.
>
> 4> Failing that, it uses the global LANGUAGE_CODE setting.

Now, you see it will check `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting as the last resort.

So, you can use HTTP-request interceptor in browser and change the `accepted-language` value to test your language translation on the fly.